# iOS How to implement Tab Bar View Controller with no tab bar item selected?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, ios9

I have gone through almost all question related to this on Stack Overflow

What I what to do is to show TabBarViewController as in the image.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this in my tab bar view controller app?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `selectedIndex` to `NSNotFound`? It's the only thing I can think of as Tab Bar Controller's are designed to always have a selected Tab.

Comment: Tab bar controllers control which view controller is on the screen. If you have no selected tabs, then what do you want to display? Which Viiew Controller?

Comment: This link might help you mate "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914531/select-no-tabs-in-a-uitabbar"

Comment: @RoboticCat Yes but no luck :(

Comment: @Abizern What I want to show is one other view controller which is not the part of the `TabBarViewController`

Comment: @gurmandeep Thanks for the link I need to test it first.

Answer (score 3):

NO, there needs to be at least one Tab selected. By default the Tab bar will select the first view controller object.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use Tabbar more flexible, you can use a customView instead of TabBarViewController's tabor, just like:

```
UIView *customTabBar = [[UIView alloc] init];    
customTabBar.frame = self.tabBar.bounds;      
[self.tabBar addSubview:customTabBar];
```